# How to make a fixed middle button merging with same gradient as a div with 100% height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have block with gradient from top(black) to bottom(blue) with 400px width and 100% height fixed at right side of the browser. There is a button as well with 50px width and 100px height at the left and vertically middle of this block. I want same block gradient merging this button as well so it will look attached with this block. Any solution using css or js? example given in screenshot.

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: It's really hard to tell if you don't include your code (is it a linear-gradient? Is it box-shadow? How is the button done? Questions over questions). Edit your post and include your HTML, CSS and Javascript so we can better understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `background-attachement:fixed` and apply the same gradient to the button:

```css
.box {
  width:400px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,red, blue) fixed;
}
.button {
  writing-mode:vertical-lr;
  font-size:23px;
  position:absolute;
  top:30%;
  left:-30px;
  padding:5px;
  color:#fff;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,red, blue) fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="button">a button</div>
</div>
```